# Use MYSQL AES_DECRYPT function in eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent, slim

I am using Slim Framework with eloquent ORM for database operations, I want to store encrypted data in the database(MYSQL) for fewer columns of particular tables.

I have tried with `AES_ENCRYPT`in eloquent model which stored the data well with mutators like,

```
class MyDataModel extends Model {

    public function setProcessDataAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['process_data'] = 
            DB::raw("AES_ENCRYPT('".$value."', '12345')");
    }

}
```

Now, I want to decrypt with the MYSQL function `AES_DECRYPT`, is there any way to use MYSQL functions in the eloquent model?

I am not sure how can I override the find, get methods in my model.

Comment: Side note: MySQL's `AES_ENCRYPT` isn't a aggregate function this just a function returning a string.

Comment: I can see there is a Crypt library in [Slim](https://github.com/fobiaweb/Slim/blob/master/Slim/Crypt.php), have you checked it out?

Comment: Why not create method inside model that execute raw SQL?

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5, recommend use his AES encryption:

```
$newEncrypter = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter('your key or app_key@env', config('app.cipher') );
$decrypted = $newEncrypter->decrypt('your encrypted data');
```